# How to refer to class instances from the class itself

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a class 'Scene'. From this class I can have several choices (0..n). They will be presented to the User of Scene object with a simple sentence (String). Each of the choices must point to a Scene instance (the next_scene). So I only need to associate this choice with a scene instance Id.
How can I implement that in Django Models, and/or in django model.Admin.
Example of a class Scene :

```
class Scene(model.Models)    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    choices = # TODO
```

I have tried several solutions but get always blocked. I suspect I do not conceive it right from the beginning. Any help would appreciated.
Stéphane

Comment: Have you tried `ManyToMany` relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for such thing is `ManyToMany` relation. You can set it to the same model:

```
class Scene(models.Model):
    ...
    choices = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does answer the question, but do not solve my problem has it has evolved. I also certainly have badly express it. I am gonna ask a new question taking into account a more complex situation.

Comment: You can tick that answer. Ill try to help with another one later, if I can.

Comment: It is done. Thanks.